# Managing screens in Qt UI development

Tags: qt, user-interface

How can we manage multiple screens while developing any UI application?

When we move from screen1 to screen 2, do we delete screen1 or keep it?

What is best approach? Deleting previous screens as we proceed or keep all the screens alive in memory?

Answer (score 0):

I really like to approach this situation (if not using qml) to keep pages that need the load something always open but invisible, and pages that do not need to load things that take time i delete and create them.

Example: If i have a login page, i would delete the page and create once is requested. If i have a page that is loading a file, i would create that page in my constructor and already starting loading the file to that page

You also have to think of the scope of that object, if more functions of your main is going to use features the best approach is to make the Ui invisible and keep the object open